# Guava multiple ratelimiter

Tags: java, guava, rate-limiting

I want to use Guava to limit the access to an API.

This API has four rate-limit:

- 20 per one second
- 100 per two minutes
- 20000 per ten seconds
- 1200000 per ten minutes

I have two problems:

1. How can I use multiple RateLimiter?
2. I am using, for example, `RateLimiter.create(120.0/100)` to limit the 100 times per two minutes, is this working in the right way?

Comment: Your `120.0/100` should be changed to `100/120.0` which literally reads 100 permits per 120 seconds.

Comment: @yegodm But it is not working how I want... it takes a lot of time to perform the operations, and it should not do that, should be instantaneous if it is not near to reach the limit.

Comment: That's due to the `RateLimiter` distributes permits on a fixed rate.

Comment: is it possible to use timedSemaphore, but, when it gets the limit, just finish the execution?

Comment: Maybe this will do https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/concurrent/TimedSemaphore.html.

Comment: Please check the numbers. In the order given, converted to seconds, your time values are 1, 120, 10, 600.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a long running job and you're making many requests, just pick the slowest limit, and configure the RateLimiter to not allow any bursts. But technically, you could create any number of RateLimiter's, and ask each of them for a permit for every single call. Exercise for the reader: try to implement both and see if there's a difference :).